# How can I store the conditions of a query Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How can I store the conditions of a query into a variable so that I can call it later? I have a get method that returns a Builder, not a collection.

```
if($a == 1) {
  $query = Review::query()
                  //many completely different conditions
                  ->where('product_id', $data['product_id']);
}
if($a == 2) {
  $query = Review::query()
                  //many completely different conditions
                  ->where('product_id', $data['product_id']);
}
$reviews = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use when()

```
$query = Review::query()
    ->when($a == 1, function($query){
        $query->where('', '');
    })
    ->when($a == 2, function($query){
        $query->where('', '');
    })
    ->where('product_id', $data['product_id'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my conditions are very different, I gave an unsuccessfully simplified example. Edited the question.

Comment: @Sergey Edited answer

Comment: Wow, that should work, thank you!